# Sort an MDX cross join

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, mdx

I'm new to MDX so bear with me.

I have crossed joined two dimensions so that I can report on Sales & Target (from the sales dimension) with this week and this week last year (from the date dimension) in columns and listed locations in the rows.

Psuedo code..

```
Select 
    {[DateDim].[ReportingPeriod].[Week].&[2012]&[20],
     [DateDim].[ReportingPeriod].[Week].&[2013]&[20]}
    *
    {[Measures].[Total Sales],[Measures].[Target]} on Columns,

    DrillDownLevel([LocationDim].[LocationName].[All]) on Rows from [MyCube]
```

How do I sort the results by sales this year? (.. `[2013].[20]`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha, worked it out!

The answer is to calculate the figure separately and then reference it within an order function

```
With Member SalesTY as
    SUM([Measures].[Total Sales,[DateDim].[ReportingPeriod].[Week].&[2013]&[20])


Select 
    {[DateDim].[ReportingPeriod].[Week].&[2012]&[20],
     [DateDim].[ReportingPeriod].[Week].&[2013]&[20]}
    *
    {[Measures].[Total Sales],[Measures].[Target]} on Columns,

    Order([LocationDim].[LocationName].[LocationName],SalesTY,DESC) on Rows from [MyCube]
```